# Equivalent of comma operator in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab

In JavaScript and C and some other languages, there is a comma operator that lets you write things like `(e1, e2)`, where `e1` and `e2` are expressions, and have it evaluate `e1`, discard the result, then evaluate `e2`. This is often useful when transforming source code.

Is there a way to do something similar in MATLAB? For example, if I have this code:

```
a = f() + g()
```

I'd like to somehow do this:

```
a = (disp('about to call f'), f()) + (disp('about to call g'), g())
```

This would print `about to call f`, then call `f`, then print `about to call g`, then call `g`. But I don't want to change the structure of the code or introduce new statements. Is that possible?

Comment: I *almost* get it, but what does `a` contain when that line has run to completion?

Comment: @BobGilmore I would assume it would contain `f() + g()`

Comment: @BobGilmore It should contain the result of calling `f() + g()`. The transformed expressions should preserve the values that the original expressions evaluate to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you could just write a function:

```
function varargout = display_then_run(fun, varargin)
    fprintf('about to call %s\n', func2str(fun));
    [varargout{1:nargout}] = fun(varargin{:});
end
```

and now

```
a = display_then_run(@f) + display_then_run(@g)
```

Comment: I like this. That happens to be enough for me, but is there a way to do it for arbitrary expressions, not just function calls?

Comment: I don't know. I don't really understand why you want to do this to be honest. If it's for debugging or just to supply user feedback on a long running script, wouldn't it be more readable to just use temp variable and run each function on it's own line with the `disp` (which should be `fprintf`, woops I'll fix that)?

Comment: It's for an automatic code transformation -- I want to preserve the behavior, but introduce tracing/profiling code before some expressions. Introducing new variables would also work but may be a bit more complicated to implement.